# Precision adjustment in biomarker analyses

Tags: causality, biostatistics, epidemiology

In a causal modeling framework, we are concerned with measuring an association between an exposure and an outcome. To do that, we usually fit a regression model for the outcome as the "y" on the exposure "x". We typically present such results with careful attention to the causal language, tending to interpret things using terms like association. This serves to reduce the number of assumptions necessary to ensure our interpretation is correct. For instance, when there is reverse causality (Y actually causes X), the associative language is still correct.

In looking for biomarkers, the causality is almost necessarily reversed. We know Y is causing X, but we definitively look at regression models treating Y as the outcome. For instance, in case control studies, the modeled probabilities from a logistic regression model simply represent the chances of being included in the sample as a case.

From a causal perspective, the rationale for fitting multivariate models boils down to a couple things: is a certain variable a confounder? Is a certain variable a precision variable. There is usually no rationale for including any variable not fitting those criteria based on a conceptual model, due to the risk they may be colliders or mediators (which would bias results if included). A precision variable simply predicts the outcome and is independent of the exposure. An example is controlling for age in looking for risk factors of obesity in children, since age strongly affects the changes in body weight.

If you are looking for a biomarker, and have identified something as a precision variable in the sense that it affects an outcome, but you are fitting a model regression the outcome on the exposure, in a sense, would you opt to include such a variable in a model? For instance, with Alzhiemer's disease, hippocampal atrophy is a strong predictor of disease but is not routinely or cheaply measured. However, cognitive tests are frequently applied and are cheap. One's cognition is certainly affected by AD and hippocampal atrophy. So we regress atrophy as an outcome on cognition as an exposure. However, we have identified other (genetic) risk factors for Alzheimer's disease.

Does the causal model framework suggest adding the genetic markers (precision vars) to this analysis?

Comment: A couple of things to think about: My concern here is that you mention the tests being expensive and not routinely measured, which indicates that there is some kind of selection factor into getting the test done.  What proportion of your study sample has the genetic markers?  5%? 10%?  Fewer?  What kind of patients are more likely to get the tests done?  Second, what additional information would having the genetic marker be added ?  Does it predict disease 100% of the time?  If so, it wouldn't be useful because you need variation in the data to fit the model.

Comment: @marquisdecarabas all participants had extensive testing, so no selection bias. It's a representative sample. The testing we did in the study would certainly never be acceptable for routine clinical practice, too expensive and invasive. Cognitive tests are quick and easy, though.

Comment: If that is the case, I don't see why you should leave the genetic markers out (given that there is variation in outcome for those with genetic markers).  Controlling for genetic markers would give you the effect of the cognitive test after controlling for the genetic stuff.  You can even see the difference in the coefficients of the cognitive test with and without genetic markers.  What would be even cooler is if you had a panel, so you can see changes over time and strengthen the causal claim.  It's fair to say that many of us are salivating over the kind of data that you have...